# Нужна ли запятая? Какое правило ее наличие определяет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, ссп, и

«Если тенденция сохранится, то к 2026 году расхождение показателей станет критичным и учёным придётся впервые за всё время убавить от суток одну секунду».

Склоняюсь к тому, что запятая не нужна в главном предложении перед «и учёным»...  Верно ли мое суждение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Придаточное предложение ***Если тенденция сохранится*** в равной степени относится к обоим предложениям сложносочиненной части, поэтому запятая перед ***и*** не нужна.

**[Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133)** (справочник Розенталя)

> <...>
> 2. Перед союзами ***и, да*** (в значении ***и***), ***или***, ***либо*** запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо **общим элементом**.
> <...>
> 2) Общей может быть **придаточная часть** сложноподчиненного предложения:
>
> *Когда Аню провожали домой, то уже светало **и** кухарки шли на рынок* (Ч.); *Пока я умывался, печь была затоплена **и** на сковородке кипело масло.*